# ember-google-map in ember cli: 'markerViewClass must be a subclass' error

Tags: google-maps, ember.js, ember-cli

I tried to implement the basic example for ember-google-map given in https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-google-map

Installed the add-on using command *npm install ember-google-map*

Here is my code:
// app/controllers/application.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';

import {MAP_TYPES} from '../components/google-map';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({

  lat:         0,
  lng:         0,
  zoom:        5,
  type:        'road',
  mapTypes:    MAP_TYPES,

});

{{! app/templates/application.hbs }}

{{google-map lat=lat lng=lng type=type zoom=zoom}}
```

I set my google map api key in config/environment.js

When I run ember server I get the following error:

> Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: markerViewClass must be a subclass
>   or an instance of Ember.View, not ember.js:3865
>   Ember.assertember.js:6919 handlebarsGetViewember.js:8534
>   collectionHelperember.js:9182 eachHelpergoogle-map.js:52
>   anonymoushandlebars.js:436 (anonymous function)ember.js:42299
>   CoreView.extend.renderember.js:39526
>   EmberRenderer_createElementember.js:10628
>   Renderer_renderTreeember.js:10705 (anonymous function)ember.js:679
>   DeferredActionQueues.invokeember.js:749
>   DeferredActionQueues.flushember.js:135 Backburner.endember.js:190
>   Backburner.runember.js:18223 runember.js:2542
>   runInitializejquery.js:3143 firejquery.js:3255
>   self.fireWithjquery.js:3467 jQuery.extend.readyjquery.js:3498
>   completed.

Is this an error in addon? Or should I modify my code?

Comment: I'm getting the same error, did you manage to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Please report this error with the verion of the addon you are using on the github repository issues, and add the version of ember CLI and EmberJS too ;-) I'll be pleased to help you!